# Type of sentence that includes a adjective phrase

Tags: types-of-sentences

Is the sentence

> The police is looking for the culprit who is suspected to be the
>   mastermind

A simple,compound or complex sentence. I think it is a simple sentence

Comment: The sentence is complex because the verb "is" takes a gerund-participial clause "looking for the culprit who is suspected to be the mastermind" as a complement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a *complex* sentence because it contains one independent clause and one relative clause.

*Independent clause*

> The police are looking for the culprit

*Relative clause*

> who is suspected to be the mastermind

There is an error in the subject-verb agreement of the sentence. 'Police' is one of those tricky collective nouns that always treats the group as individuals and is considered plural even when discussing them as a group.

Answer (score 1):

This is a complex sentence.

It consists of the ***main clause*** 
(The police is looking for the culprit)

and the ***[defining relative  clause](https://www.ef.com/wwen/english-resources/english-grammar/relative-clauses/)***

(who is suspected to be the mastermind).